# Pass parameter to In query in C# and SQL Server 2005

Tags: c#, sql-server, parameters

I need to pass this string parameter value via C# application to a SQL Server query:

```
'foo', 'bar'
```

This is the query in the code-behind:

```
sql = @String.Format(" SELECT * FROM ");
sql += String.Format("  [dbo].[PDTM] ");
sql += String.Format(" WHERE ");
sql += String.Format(" PDTM IN (@param1); ");

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("param1", txtPDTM.Text.ToString());
```

But this does not work yet because the output is empty.

Then I try to change the SQL query to:

```
sql = @String.Format(" SELECT * FROM ");
sql += String.Format("  [dbo].[PDTM] ");
sql += String.Format(" WHERE ");
sql += String.Format(" PDTM IN (" + txtPDTM.Text.ToString() + "); ");
```

And this works.

So what is the correct way to pass parameter to IN query in C#?

Comment: `PDTM IN (@param1)` would result in `PDTM IN ('''foo'', ''bar''')`; which isn't what you're expecting I'm sure. If you need to pass multiple values you need to either use a table-value parameter or a string splitter; both of which are difficult to do in a version of SQL Server that hasn't been supported for 5~ years. I strongly suggest it long past time to upgrade.

Comment: The second way, however, is certainly not the "correct" way to do it; that is a massive injection risk.

Comment: It's really beyond time to update. 2005 fell out of even *extended* support back in 2016 (assuming latest service pack).

Comment: The typical way to handle this is with one paramter for each value.  You might want to check out Dapper which handles that for you.  But like Larnu said you'd have to split that original string up and remove the single quotes.

Comment: That works with you have a defined number, @juharr , but when you have a variable number, it doesn't. True, there isn't enough information to determine if there are a defined number or not, however, I would suggest without the OP stating otherwise it's safe to assume that it could be any number between 1 and "lots".

Comment: @Larnu Thanks you all for reply. The service provider have update SQL Server to 2016 version,but I have the same problem with this string `'foo', 'bar'`

Answer (score 0):

This is a function **fn_split_string** which splits a string:

```
ALTER function dbo.fn_split_string(@str nvarchar(1000),@sep nvarchar(1))
returns @tab_split  table (id int identity(1,1),str nvarchar(1000) )  
as  

begin  
declare @str1 as nvarchar(1000)  
declare @istr as nvarchar(1000)  
declare @i as integer  
set @str1=@str  
set @i=2  
while @i>0 
begin  
set @i=charindex(@sep,@str1,1)  
if @i>0  
begin  
set @istr=substring(@str1,1,@i-1)  
insert into @tab_split(str) values(@istr)  
set @str1=substring(@str1,@i+1,len(@str1))  
end  
end  
insert into @tab_split(str) values(@str1)  
return   
end
```

And running the function as follows :

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.fn_split_string ('foo, bar',',');
```

The output is :

```
1   foo
2   bar
```

It would be something  such as :

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.PDTM WHERE PDTM IN (SELECT str FROM dbo.fn_split_string(@param1,','))
```

As pointed already the next one is to pass directly a list of string to your SQL statement.

Hope this can help you.

Best regards,